# Datastore plugin has not been added to amplify Flutter

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify, flutter-aws-amplify

I follow the Amplify tutorial to make a todo app and got this error in return on the fist run anyone know why ? I have read another similar question on Stackoverflow but it didn't solve the problem for me so is there any other way. [image]

Comment: Take a look at how to initialize Amplify: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/project-setup/create-application/q/platform/flutter/#4-initialize-amplify-in-the-application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it didn't gave out the error but I got some thing wrong in the console. There is one that said: "E/SurfaceSyncer( 5435): Failed to find sync for id=0" and one that said "W/Parcel ( 5435): Expecting binder but got null!". Do you know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of your code is that it starts to use the DataStore **without first initializing it**.

The DataStore works as a `plugin` of the whole Amplify Flutter framework.
So besides creating one DataStore plugin which you have done at line:47 of your code, you still have to ***plug the plugin*** to `Amplify`.

The solution is to move the creation of DataStore plugin into `initState` then add few more lines of code after that.

```
void initState(){

  // Your code of creating plugin
  final _dataStorePlugin = AmplifyDataStore(modelProvider: ModelProvide.instance)

  // add Amplify plugins
  Amplify.addPlugins([_dataStorePlugin]).then((_) {

    // configure Amplify
    //
    // note that Amplify cannot be configured more than once!
    return Amplify.configure(amplifyconfig);
});

}
```

Or follow the tutorial [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/integrate/q/integration/flutter/#configure-amplify)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it didn't gave out the error but I got some thing wrong in the console. There is one that said: "E/SurfaceSyncer( 5435): Failed to find sync for id=0" and one that said "W/Parcel  ( 5435): Expecting binder but got null!". Do you know why

Comment: Seems that the Amplify didn’t find a backend to sync with. You can still use the offline mode and ignoring the error, or provision a backend with amplify. 

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/sync/q/platform/flutter/